# tensorflow, custom loss, custom_gradient, temp tf.Variable leads to error

Tags: python, tensorflow, debugging, gradient, autodiff

Consider implementing a custom loss function that requires a temporary variable instantiation. If we need to implement custom gradients, TF expects there to be an additional output of the gradient functional, when there should only be as many components of the gradient as there is inputs of the loss function. That is, if my understanding is correct. Any corrections are appreciated.

Linking related github issue, which contains a minimal working example (MWE) and additional debugging information: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31945

The MWE here, copy-pasted from the github post is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# from custom_gradient import custom_gradient  # my corrected version
from tensorflow import custom_gradient


def layer(t, name):
    var = tf.Variable(1.0, dtype=tf.float32, use_resource=True, name=name)
    return t * var


@custom_gradient
def custom_gradient_layer(t):
    result = layer(t, name='outside')

    def grad(*grad_ys, variables=None):
        assert variables is not None
        print(variables)
        grads = tf.gradients(
            layer(t, name='inside'),
            [t, *variables],
            grad_ys=grad_ys,
        )
        grads = (grads[:1], grads[1:])
        return grads

    return result, grad
```

Which will throw `ValueError: not enough values to unpack...`.

If my understanding is correct, usually for the adjoint method (reverse mode autodiff), the forward pass builds the expression tree, and for the reverse pass we evaluate the gradients, and the gradient functional is value times the partial derivative of the function we'd take the derivative with respect to, which could be a composite function. I can post a reference if needed.

So, with one input variable, we'd have one evaluation of the gradient. Here, TF expects 2, even though we only have one input variable, because of the temp variable, which is unavoidable in some cases.

My MWE pseudo code is something like this:

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_loss(in):

    temp = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2 * N - 1]), dtype = tf.float32)

    ## compute loss function
    ...

     def grad(df):
         grad = df * partial_derivative
         return grad

    return loss, grad
```

Andre

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I find that adding trainable=False resolves the issue for me. E.g. the following

```
import tensorflow as tf
@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_loss(x):

    temp = tf.Variable(1., dtype = tf.float32)

    loss = x*temp

     def grad(dL):
         grad = dL * temp
         return grad

    return loss, grad
```

gives me error "TypeError: If using @custom_gradient with a function that uses variables, then grad_fn must accept a keyword argument 'variables'."

But I get no error if I instead do

```
import tensorflow as tf
@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_loss(x):

    temp = tf.Variable(1., dtype = tf.float32, trainable=False)

    loss = x*temp

     def grad(dL):
         grad = dL * temp
         return grad

    return loss, grad
```

Hope this helps you or someone else.